# Asp.net core 2.2 mvc 5 routing for more subfolders in Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, .net-core-2.2

I am trying to make a website application with following structure of Views:

```
Views
    Admin
        Player
            Index
            Create
            Update
    Client
        Index
```

and so on...

The issue is, how do I deal with routing since I have 2 subfolders in Views?

I tried to specify the route in the controller by:

```
return View("~/Views/Admin/Player/Index.cshtml");
```

and in the startup file:

```
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "player",
                    template: "admin/Player"
                    );
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");   
            });
```

Sadly I cannot get to the address like https://localhost:5001/Admin/Player/ (returns a error 404)

but I get to the view by using address: https://localhost:5001/Player

Could somebody explain to me why it works like that? And how to get around it? I am tangled in that and cannot find my way out. 
Thank you guys!

Comment: Just read about Areas in ASP.NET MVC [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC)

Comment: I was thinking about Areas, but I didn't want to change a structure of the whole project (the structure above was example), but I guess that will be the best option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route for admin/Player doesnt specify what controller it will select. Your default route would work otherwise if you have a controller called AdminController with a method called Player.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that, although do you have recommendation how would syntax look since I use two subfolders? So I would be able to get to the player as https://localhost:5001/Admin/Player/? If I didn't use areas

Comment: @R.Traymer Controllers arent affected by your folder structure but are identified by their classnames.

So for example you could write:

    routes.MapRoute(
        "player",
        template: "admin/Player",
        new {controller = "Admin", action = "Player"});

Comment: @R.Traymer You can also add routing on the controller using RouteAttribute decorator like [Route("admin/Player")] and your index method will use that route. Or you can set the RouteAttribute on an individual method.